# find a pattern and edit the next line and write back to the same file using python

Tags: python-3.x, file, find, edit

I have a text file **foo.txt** that looks like :

```
I dont care!
pattern and stuff
this line : to_edit
this line : no_edit
some other lines
this line : to_edit
pattern and stuff
another line : to_edit
another line : to_edit
```

I want to find *pattern* and edit **only the next line** and **no other line** and write back to the same **foo.txt** like so :

```
I dont care!
pattern and stuff
this line : EDITED
this line : no_edit
some other lines
this line : to_edit
pattern and stuff
another line : EDITED
another line : to_edit
```

I also don't want to use f.readline() and f.seek() The code I have so far that looks like this:

```
import re
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close
def replace(foo.txt):
    searchPattern = re.compile("^pattern")
    pattern = "to_edit"
    subst = "EDITED"
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    nextLine = 0
    with open(abs_path,'w') as new_file:
        with open(file_path) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                if nextLine == 0:
                    if searchPattern.search(line):
                        nextLine = 1
                        continue
                    else:
                        new_file.write(line)
                else:
                    new_file.write(re.sub(pattern,subst,line))
                    nextLine = 0
    close(fh)
    remove(foo.txt)
    move(abs_path, foo.txt)
```

I fell this is a very inefficient way of coding and getting the solution.

Comment: You could put everything into the regular expression, but I think this might be *less* efficient than your current solution so you can just ignore this comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code is missing some things (like `searchPattern` being a string and not having the `search` attribute), but you could use `next()` to get the next line from the file iterator when you find the search pattern.

Adapting from your code:

```
def replace(foo.txt):
    searchPattern = re.compile("^pattern")
    pattern = "to_edit"
    subst = "EDITED"
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with open(abs_path,'w') as new_file:
        with open(file_path) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                # As it is, this next line should not work, but assuming that it returns True when the pattern is found..
                if searchPattern.search(line):
                    # Write current line
                    new_file.write(line)
                    # Get next line
                    next_line = next(old_file)
                    # Write edited line 
                    new_file.write(re.sub(pattern,subst,next_line))
                else:
                    new_file.write(line)
```

Comment: I corrected the code i forgot to add re.compile() to search pattern that was why it was throwing the error.   With your code will not it write the line twice one with edited and other with to_edit? Please corret me if i am wrong

Comment: When you use `next()` on the `old_file` iterator, it will retrieve (and exhaust) the next line into the `next_line` variable. This means that in the next iteration in the `for line in old_file` loop, the `line` variable will be the line after the to_edit line.